# How to run simple calculations in shell scripts

Tags: batch-processing

i want to run the following

```
For i in A*.wav
do
soundstretch $i B$i -tempo=n
done
```

but i wan n to be (2/(soxi -D $i)-1)*100.

how do i code that?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
n=$(echo "(2/(soxi - D $1)-1)-100" | bc)
```

though I cant parse the expression you are trying to evaluate. I mean I dont know what soxi and D is. echo prints the expression, which is then piped into bc and whatever that prints to its stdout is then assigned to n.

Comment: soxi -D $1 

just tells me how long the file is in seconds. my expression does work, but i seem unable to run it with the echo command as you suggested.

i am also unsure if i should just add your line in with just under "do" in my original script.

my apologies if you are right, but i'm still stuck!

Comment: Since you are iterating over .wav files, presumably, the length of the file in seconds change too, you have to recalculate the expression for every wav file, so the evaluation goes inside the 'do' loop. What shell are you using? If it is ancient try to surround the expression with backticks instead of $(). Is soxi a shell variable or perhaps a program which determines the length in seconds?